# Couldn't Update single data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, api, express

I'm trying to update single data using the id as a parameters, but when I send the data as an JSON object it returns null when I console log the passed JSON Object.

This is what I've done to update data.

```
// Update By Id
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        return res.status(400).send(`No records with given id : ${req.params.id}`);
    }
    var emp = {
        name : req.body.name,
        position : req.body.position,
        office : req.body.office,
        salary : req.body.salary
    };

    Employee.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {$set : emp}, {new : true}, (err, doc) => {
        if(!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else { console.log('Error in Employee Update : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});
```

Data I passed into request body.

```
{
    "name": "Some Name",
    "position": "A Position",
    "office": "Location Name",
    "salary": 60000
}
```

When I try to console log the data I passed it returns undefined and all data are updated by null.

```
console.log(emp.name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how but somehow the above code is working fine with a little bit of modification and restarting the server again.

This is what I've modified

```
Employee.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {$set : emp}, {new : true}, (err, doc)
```

To

```
Employee.findByIdAndUpdate( req.params.id , {$set : emp}, {new : true}, (err, doc)
```

Thanks to **Fanpark**